# Redirect request from https domain to https subdomain with only one certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, redirect

I'm trying to redirect users to a subdomain in `server2` if they make an https request to `server1`. I only have one certificate, and that's installed on `server2`.

So for instance, from `(server1) https://www.example.com` to `(server2) https://ssl.example.com`

My best guess is that I will need a certificate for https://www.example.com as the hostname is encrypted inside the HTTP header so my server won't know to redirect until it's decrypted. However, I'm curious if this is possible without two certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with one certificate, it just needs to have two `subjectAltName` parameters, one for `www.example.com` and `ssl.example.com`.  I do wonder why you would redirect someone to an SSL-specific subdomain if you've already got them using SSL on the main domain...

Comment: Mainly I was thinking in the case that a user types `https://www.example.com`. If they follow the links within `www.example.com`, then it will automatically send them to `ssl.example.com`. 

My other question would be, `server1` is a name based server (virtualhosts) (1 IP), so using `SAN` could create conflicts/warnings between the other sites. is that correct?

Comment: Why have `ssl.example.com` at *all*, though?  Why not just run all your SSL through `www.example.com`, if you've got a cert for it.  You'll have conflicts with other name-based virtual hosts on the same IP *regardless* of whether you're using sAN; there's no way to avoid that.

Comment: I agree with you, using only www would be the way to go. Thanks!