# For DNS and SSL do I need a separate certificate for every (DNS RR) A record?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, subdomain, cname-record

So our firm wants to separate out our cloud servers into separate environments, so www.example.com, test.example.com and dev.example.com. [We may even want to break our subdomains into further sub-domains.] My boss wants to know how many certificates (for SSL) the firm will need.

I have delved into subdomains and looks like a question of DNS RR (Domain Name Server Resource Records). I have seen notes about A records and CNAME records and how they interplay. I am thinking that a mixture of A and CNAME records should suffice to separate out our namespace.

What of the certificates though, do we need an SSL certificate for every A record? My boss is keen to reduce cost (as are all bosses).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect request from https domain to https subdomain with only one certificate](http://serverfault.com/questions/405780/redirect-request-from-https-domain-to-https-subdomain-with-only-one-certificate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each identity that one of your servers will assume (that is, each name a server will identify itself as), you'll need to have a certificate that matches that identity. An identity doesn't necessarily equal a DNS entry, but in cases when it does (such as web servers), it makes no difference whether the entries are CNAME or A (or even AAAA) records.

To make things a bit more complicated to understand, you don't necessarily need a different certificate for each identity. One single certificate may certify many identities (one primary and several alternate), and there are also the so-called wildcard certificates that can be used for any subdomain of a given domain (e.g. if you have a wildcard certificate for *.example.com, you can use it for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and anythingyouwant.example.com without having to have any of those two names explicitly listed in the certificate). However, wildcard certificates are more expensive than regular ones. While regular certs usually cost a couple tens of dollars, a wildcard cert typically goes for hundreds. Note that there are some certification authorities who will give you free regular certificates with certain limitations (for example, StartCom's basic [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) certificates are free, but can contain only two names, one of which has to be the root domain).

In your example, you have 3 identities (these are `www.example.com`, `test.example.com`, and `dev.example.com`). For you, for now, I'd recommend getting 3 free certificates. If you ever get to the point where you need 20-30 different certs, you should consider buying a wildcard cert, as the costs (of the work hours) of having to renew 20-30 expiring certs manually each year would be higher than that of a wildcard cert.

Comment: "However, wildcard certificates are more expensive than regular ones." This is not true anymore today as at least one CA is delivering free certificates, wildcard or not.